# Template Metaprogramming to calculate Fibonacci

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, fibonacci, biginteger

Recently in a job interview I was asked to give the result of 100th element of a 3rd-class Fibonacci sequence(Fib(n)=Fib(n-1)+Fib(n-2)+Fib(n-3). I finished by Mathematical Induction and constructing a class to present numbers larger than long long. Then I was asked to implement it via template meta-programming. The problem is that the result will exceed the range of long long and I don't know how to fix this. Here is my code using template meta-programming.

```
template<long long num>
struct fib
{
    enum { result = fib<num - 1>::result + fib<num - 2>::result + fib<num - 3>::result};
};

template<>
struct fib<0>
{
    enum { result = 1 };
};

template<>
struct fib<1>
{
    enum { result = 1 };
};

template<>
struct fib<2>
{
    enum { result = 2 };
};

template<>
struct fib<3>
{
    enum { result = 4 };
};

int main()
{

    cout << fib<100>::result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Holt oh missed that

Comment: You could store the number in some kind of class that stores the digits, e.g., `template <int... Digits> struct Number;`. Fibonacci sequence only require addition, so you only have to implement an addition. You could even represent the number in base-2 for simpler addition.

Comment: Note that you starting number are (I think wrong), you should  have 0, 0, 1 according to https://oeis.org/A000073.

Comment: do you nkow the correct answer?

Comment: @max66 With 64 bits `long long`, the limit is reached at `fib<72>` (signed long long) or `fib<73>` (unsigned long long)

Comment: @DavideCastronovo OP *is* using (compile-time) recursion. This hint doesn’t solve the issue with OP’s code regarding the range of integer data types.

Comment: I think the correct term is "3rd order" sequence, not 3rd class.

Comment: @James Reinstate Monica Polk Thanks for your correction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A possible implementation is to use a custom structure to store the numbers instead of a built-in type. You could for instance store numbers like this:

```
template <int... Digits>
struct number<Digits... > { };
```

*Note:* For the sake of simplicity when adding, I store the digits in reverse order, so the number `275` is stored as `number<5, 7, 2>`.

Fibonacci only requires addition, so you simply have to define addition, e.g., a template `add` (see the end of the answer for the actual implementation).

You can then define the `fib` template quite easily:

```
template <int N>
struct fib_impl {
    using type = add_t<
        typename fib_impl<N-1>::type, 
        typename fib_impl<N-2>::type,
        typename fib_impl<N-3>::type>;
};

template <>
struct fib_impl<0> { using type = number<0>; };
template <>
struct fib_impl<1> { using type = number<0>; };
template <>
struct fib_impl<2> { using type = number<1>; };

template <int N>
using fib = typename fib_impl<N>::type;
```

And with an appropriate output operator (see below), you can print the 100th Tribonacci number:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << fib<100>{} << "\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
53324762928098149064722658
```

While the 100th is not present in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000073/list), you can check that the 37th one is correct:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<fib<37>, number<2, 5, 8, 6, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1>>);
```

---

#### Implementation of `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, number<>) {
    return out;
}

template <int Digit, int... Digits>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, number<Digit, Digits... >) {
    // Do not forget that number<> is in reverse order:
    return out << number<Digits... >{} << Digit;
}
```

#### Implementation of the `add` template:

1. This is a small `cat` utility to concatenate numbers:

```
// Small concatenation utility:
template <class N1, class N2>
struct cat;

template <int... N1, int... N2>
struct cat<number<N1... >, number<N2... >> {
    using type = number<N1... , N2...>;
};

template <class N1, class N2>
using cat_t = typename cat<N1, N2>::type;
```

2. The actual implementation of the addition:

```
template <class AccNumber, int Carry, class Number1, class Number2>
struct add_impl;

template <class AccNumber, int Carry>
struct add_impl<AccNumber, Carry, number<>, number<>> {
    using type = std::conditional_t<Carry == 0, AccNumber, cat_t<AccNumber, number<1>>>;
};

template <class AccNumber, int Carry,
          int Digit2, int... Digits2>
struct add_impl<AccNumber, Carry, number<>, number<Digit2, Digits2...>> {
    using type = typename add_impl<
        cat_t<AccNumber, number<(Digit2 + Carry) % 10>>,
        (Digit2 + Carry) / 10,
        number<Digits2... >, number<>>::type;
};
template <class AccNumber, int Carry,
          int Digit1, int... Digits1>
struct add_impl<AccNumber, Carry, number<Digit1, Digits1... >, number<>> {
    using type = typename add_impl<
        cat_t<AccNumber, number<(Digit1 + Carry) % 10>>,
        (Digit1 + Carry) / 10,
        number<Digits1... >, number<>>::type;
};

template <class AccNumber, int Carry,
          int Digit1, int... Digits1, int Digit2, int... Digits2>
struct add_impl<AccNumber, Carry, number<Digit1, Digits1... >, number<Digit2, Digits2...>> {
    using type = typename add_impl<
                    cat_t<AccNumber, number<(Digit1 + Digit2 + Carry) % 10>>,
                    (Digit1 + Digit2 + Carry) / 10,
                    number<Digits1... >, number<Digits2... >>::type;
};
```

3. A short wrapper:

```
template <class... Numbers>
struct add;

template <class Number>
struct add<Number> {
    using type = Number;
};

template <class Number, class... Numbers>
struct add<Number, Numbers... > {
    using type = typename add_impl<
        number<>, 0, Number, typename add<Numbers... >::type>::type;
};


template <class... Numbers>
using add_t = typename add<Numbers... >::type;
```

Comment: i knew arbitrary number of digits would be complicated, so I tried to keep it simple ;). Anyhow, this is rather cool stuff, do you know what is the limit for digits, ie limit for number of template parameters?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I don't really know... Its probably impossible to reach the limit by computing tribonaccy numbers since it already takes ~10s on my computer to compute for `fib<400>` and the number is only 107 digits long.

Comment: You code seems correct but it would be the 98th numbers if the initial sequence is 1,1, 2,4 (as in question source code) instead of 0,0,1,1 (as in OEIS). I got `98: 5.33248e+25` using doubles.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yes, I am taking the OEIS as reference here, I already notified the OP in a comment as I think it was a mistake on their side.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot to understand template metaprogramming

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of ready-to-use arbirtrary precicion facitlities for templates. However, a toy number-type that can hold numbers bigger than `long long` is easy to write:

```
template <long long H,long long L> 
struct my_number {
    static const long long high = H;
    static const long long low = L;
    static const long long mod = 10000000000;
    static void print() {
        std::cout << high << setw(10) << setfill('0') << low;
    }
};
```

It stores the last `10` digits of the result in `low` and the leading digits in `high`. Two `my_number`s can be summed via

```
template <typename A,typename B>
struct sum {
    static const long long low = (A::low + B::low) % A::mod;
    static const long long high = A::high + B::high + (A::low + B::low) / A::mod;
    using number = my_number<high,low>;
};
```

and for 3 numbers:

```
template <typename A,typename B,typename C>
struct sum3 { using number = typename sum<A,sum<B,C>>::number; };
```

As already mentioned, this is just a toy example. Anyhow, once you have a number type that can represent big enough numbers you just have to adjust you `fib` with minor modifications:

```
template<long long num> struct fib {
    using result_t = typename sum3< typename fib<num-1>::result_t, 
                                    typename fib<num-2>::result_t,
                                    typename fib<num-3>::result_t
                                   >::number;
};

template<> struct fib<0> { using result_t = my_number<0,1>; };
template<> struct fib<1> { using result_t = my_number<0,1>; };
template<> struct fib<2> { using result_t = my_number<0,2>; };
template<> struct fib<3> { using result_t = my_number<0,4>; };

int main() {
    fib<100>::result_t::print();
}
```

I couldn't find a reliable source for the correct value of `fib<100>`, so unfortunately I couldn't test against that.

Full example is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ilOzLNUv1gLSJw4o).

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer is clean and useful. I checked your result and its correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using Boost version `1.72` and [boost::multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

template <int x>
struct fib
{
    static constexpr boost::multiprecision::uint1024_t value = x * fib<x - 1>::value;
};

template <>
struct fib<0>
{
    static constexpr boost::multiprecision::uint1024_t value = 1;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << fib<100>::value;
}
```

Output:

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

This was run using Visual Studio 2019 and boost 1.72.  Note that earlier versions of `boost::multiprecision` were not full `constexpr`, so this probably will not compile with earlier versions of boost.

EDIT:
Here is the third-class version.  This is almost verbatim to the original poster's version, with the only difference being the usage of the `constexpr`-enabled big number class from `boost`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

template<long long num>
struct fib
{
    static constexpr boost::multiprecision::uint1024_t value = fib<num - 1>::value + fib<num - 2>::value + fib<num - 3>::value;
};

template<>
struct fib<0>
{
    static constexpr boost::multiprecision::uint1024_t value = 1;
};

template<>
struct fib<1>
{
    static constexpr boost::multiprecision::uint1024_t value = 1;
};

template<>
struct fib<2>
{
    static constexpr boost::multiprecision::uint1024_t value = 2;
};

template<>
struct fib<3>
{
    static constexpr boost::multiprecision::uint1024_t value = 4;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << fib<100>::value;
}
```

Output:

```
180396380815100901214157639
```

Comment: This is standard Fibonacci and not 3rd-class Fibonacci!

Comment: With some adjustment, it should still work.  See the Edit.